# How to add these capsule shape behind the selected tab bar item image

Tags: swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to make a tab bar with the following features:

- selectd tab-bar item has this capsule shape around it's icon only , [link to desired tab-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjE0L.png)

I am creating the tab bar programmatically. Can you help me with the code?

Screenshots of the what i achieved so far : [link to screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sFVN.png)

Here is the code so far

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //MARK: Initializing tab-bar viewControllers
    let prayerVC = initiateViewController.initiatePrayerVC()
    let alarmVC = initiateViewController.initiateAlarmVC()
    let settingsVC = initiateViewController.initiateSettingsVC()
    
    //MARK: tab bar item text attributes
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12).pointSize) as Any
]

    //MARK: edit tab bar appearance & attributes
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
    
    //MARK: adding Title and image for each Tab bar item (viewcontroller)
    prayerVC.tabBarItem.title = text_international.prayer_times
    alarmVC.tabBarItem.title = text_international.alarm
    settingsVC.tabBarItem.title = text_international.settings

    prayerVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "IconPrayer")
    alarmVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "IconAlarm")
    settingsVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "IconSettings")
    
    
    //MARK: adding View Controllers to the tab bar
    self.setViewControllers([prayerVC,alarmVC,settingsVC], animated: false)
    
    
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i Use UIkit not swiftUI

Comment: Hi and welcome, to help you with the code we would need to have the code. Please edit your question to provide the required information. Don't forget to add what you tried and what is blocking you

Comment: Read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Tabbar item has a . selectedImage property. So what I would do is have unselected tabBar images and selected tabbar images.